# Can I conjugate "acyclic" as "acycle"

Tags: nouns, derivation

I was thinking about the word "acyclic" meaning not having or containing a cycle. Then I thought of the word "bicycle" and wondered if it made sense to call something that an "acycle". As an example I would want to say that stilts are an acycle (because they do not inherently contain a cycle or cyclic motion).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Referring to stilts as an "acycle" seems to me a bizarre formation. "Acyclic" is used to distinguish between things that might or should have a cycle but don't. Simply because stilts do not have a "cycle" does not make them acyclic, because stilts do not belong to a class of objects that could conceivably have a cycle. Neither do tree stumps, Frank Frazetta book covers, or fingernail parings, except in the sense that all things have a cycle of creation and destruction.

*Acyclic* refers to concepts like molecules that contain no rings of atoms, or women who don't have a menstrual cycle [see NOAD definition]. Both of those are commonly thought to have cycles, and so may require a term to describe the absence of what should be a normal property for them.

Answer (score 2):

Calling stilts an acycle makes exactly as much sense as calling them a motorless.

Comment: I don't quite understand, stilts don't have motors, thus wouldn't it makes sense to say they are motorless?

Comment: @Yoel: We aren't talking about saying they are motorless or wheel-less, we are talking about using those *as their name*.